# How to compute recall@k

Tags: rank, evaluation

How to compute recall@k, where the total number of relevant items are unknown in the repository?
One only has the number of relevant items from the top "k" items retrieved, for a given query.

Comment: I don't think you can compute Recall@k without knowing the total number of relevant items in the system. Perhaps Precision@k is a better metric for you.

Comment: Both Recall@k and Recall@k need knowing the number of relevant items.           > Recall@k=(# of recommended items @k that are relevant)/(# of recommended items @k).